# Calling header in a for loop

Tags: r

I wrote a quick for loop to make a series of NQQ plots in R. Each plot corresponds to one column of a data frame. I would like to call the header names so that I can name the plots using the columns they correspond to.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,8))
for (i in 1:8){
qqnorm(data.c[[i]],main=paste("C",data.c[1,i],sep=""))
qqline(data.c[[i]])
}
```

In its current form, this code calls the first row of data in my dataframe. How can I get it to call the header row? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, use the `colnames()` function to get the name of the columns, instead of the first row.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,8))
for (i in 1:8){
  qqnorm(data.c[[i]],main=paste("C",colnames(data.c[i]),sep=""))
  qqline(data.c[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
par(mfrow=c(1,8))
for (i in 1:8){
qqnorm(data.c[[i]],main=paste("C",names(data.c)[i], sep=""))
qqline(data.c[[i]])
}
```

Another method that might be more self-documenting would be to loop over the column names themselves:

```
for (colnam in names(data.c)[1:8] ){
    qqnorm(data.c[[colnam]], main=paste("C",colnam, sep=""))
    qqline(data.c[[colnam]])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I follow,

`names(data.c)[i]` instead of `data.c[1, i]`